# How to give styling for active tab of nav-tab

Tags: html, css, tabs

This is my HTML Code. I want css styling for active nav-tab.Now i want when my page loads Location tab should have blue background how can i get that

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 welcome">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nav-primary">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
         <span class="li-text">Location</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="li-text">Heartbeats</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="li-text">Reboots</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#four" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="li-text">Reconnects</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#five" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-battery-full" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span class="li-text">Charge</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
```

Location tab is the active tab

```
         <div id="one" class="tab-pane active">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-md-offset-10 col-xs-offset-10 col-lg-offset-10 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 searchDiv">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1">
                                <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xs-1">

                                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
                    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid-table" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-pinning ng-style="getTableHeight()"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now i want when my page loads Location tab should have blue background how can i get that.[image]

Comment: can you please share the css as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
.nav li.active a,
.nav li a:hover,
.nav li.active a:focus,
.nav li.active a:hover{
  background-color:red;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/goh8rpcm/1/)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
.tab-pane.active {
   background : blue; // or your desired color code.
}
```